# Electric Engine Heater

Tags: power

-24C tonight...shopping to replace a broken oil pan heater, an idea came up.

If I measured the resistance between 2 opposing points of an engine, could I then apply a specific voltage across the 2 points and cause it to heat? (Like a resistive load heater)

To keep it simple, let's ignore the sensors, injectors and other electronics possibly being damaged.

For an example, I just measured a resistance of 5.8 Ohm across my engine (68kg of steel/aluminium).  120v across it should pull 20amp giving 2400w.  Specific heat of aluminium is about 0.9J/gC (higher than steel so worse case)...should raise it 120C in an hour?

Comment: I think you should double-check that resistance measurement. No way you would have several ohms across an engine block. Generally for example the starter motor is grounded through the engine block, using the engine to carry hundreds of amps while cranking. That would never work with such resistance.

Comment: Or instead of doing crazy things like connecting voltages directly to the chassis ground itself, maybe mount something that generates a lot of heat next to the engine block and have it work as heat sink? For example heating element wire-wound resistors.

Comment: I suspect a lot of contact resistance in your measurement. I would expect the resistance to be futile in an engine block. Get yourself a real frost plug water heater and be done with it.

Comment: No way will that work (the actual resistance will be tiny), also dangerous. If you have to improvise to get the car started maybe a carefully placed incandescent bulb, but be careful not to damage anything from excessive heat or start a fire.

Comment: buy a magnetic engine block heater

Comment: I'll just replace my broken magnetic oil pan heater.

Was just a thought that started snowballing so i thought I'd get some opinions on its feasibility.

I was surprised by the high resistance as well.  I suppose if the resistance was an expected 0.01Ohm, a lower voltage could be used? Obviously the amperage would be quite high.

Answer (score 0):

I put a small (400W) heater under the bonnet of my car as I don’t have a garage.

I have it on a timer to come on for 3 hours before I need to leave for work.

Starts like it is a summer day, no overloading of starter or draining the battery - it’s a 2.2 litre diesel…

The heater is about 20cm by 10cm by 10cm and is cheap.

I have considered the engine heating kit which has a heater and electric pump but it is a lot more expensive and uses much more power.